# Is it possible to use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to Manage SQL Server CE Databases [*.sdf]?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am asking this because it dont work in my SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see this thread for some advice: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/01072b57-f8ae-4453-a9ea-a35a6ea975fa